# images randomly not loading

Tags: css, angular, image

We have created an angular application where we use several icons (SVG files). These icons sometimes don't show on our web page and I do not know why this is happening or how to fix this. The SVG files are mostly between 1-3kb.
We are using Angular version 6, Angular CLI version is 7+ and the web browser we use is Chrome.

The icons usually all load but sometimes when visiting the same page 1 or a few icons may not load, it seems all quite random.

Does anyone know what the problem might be and more importantly how to fix this?

Our CSS and HTML do load without a problem.

We use the images by loading them as a CSS class like so:

```
.icon-blue-stack-b {
    content: url('/assets/CPP-component_libary_3.6/Graphics/Icons/Blue/Stack-B_0.1.svg');
}
```

and then applying them like so

```
<i class="icon-blue-stack-b"></i>
```

Comment: have you been able to check the network activity for the svgs when this happens?

Comment: No unfortunatly i have not, it did cross my mind that the internet connection might not be able to handle the traffic but even if that's the case i cannot upgrade the network so i'll have to figure out a way to circumvent it if slow connection speed is the case.

Comment: ever found solution to it?

Comment: @PetarMarkovic Sorry I can't remember, I feel like it stopped happening but I cannot remember us actually knowingly fixing it.